Is solid salt also salty?
Recently in my school's Chemistry book I read that Ions lose their structure when dissolved in water. For example NaCl becomes Na+ and Cl-. And the only way we taste salt is dissolved salt(even if we eat solid salt, it will dissolve in our salivia). So my question: Is solid salt also salty?

Being salty is not a property/attribute of table salt.
It is biological property of human sensory path, from taste sensor cells to brain, as perception of table salt solution. Solid salt is not a salt solution and is not in contact with human taste sensors.
Therefore no, solid salt is not salty. Even if you put a salt crystal on your tongue, its surface layers are first dissolved, then the solution gets in contact with sensory cells, and then you feel saltiness.
Note that salty taste is mutual synergic effect of simultaneous presence of sodium and chloride ions. These ions cause much less saltiness when alone, in case of other salts that share one ion with $\ce{NaCl}$, and there are other secondary tastes perceived.
